# Differential of a contracting map is contracting

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable and contracting, in the variables $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$. I am trying to prove that the differential $d f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is also contracting. Firstly, at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the differential is given (I think) by
$$ df(a) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a) dx_1 + \cdots \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(a) dx_n . $$
So for two points $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$ |df(a) - df(b)| = | (\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+he_1)-f(x)}{h} - \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(b+he_1)-f(b)}{h}) dx_1 + \cdots + (\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+he_n)-f(a)}{h}-\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(b+he_1)-f(b)}{h} )dx_n |  $$
where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors. Then by the triangle inequality and the fact that $f$ is contracting, we get
$$ |df(a) - df(b)| \leq | \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c|a+he_1-a|}{h} dx_1 | + | \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c|b+he_1-b|}{h} dx_1 | + \cdots + | \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c|x+he_1-x|}{h} dx_n | + | \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c|b+he_1-b|}{h} dx_n | = 2nc$$
where $c$ is the contracting constant. But now we no longer have that $2nc \in [0,1)$. I have a few questions.

The first one is: how can we fix the $2nc \not\in [0,1)$ issue? Can we just choose instead of standard basis vectors, basis vectors with arbitrarily small norm. But then wouldn't this mean that the differential of $f$'s contracting constant can be made arbitrarily small?

The second one is: am I even using the correct notion of differential of $f$ here? In the problem I'm trying to solve it says to show that $df(a) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is contracting, but this seems like a misprint because I thought $df$ should be the linear map/function, and $df(a)$ should be a vector? That being said, if by $df$ we mean the Jacobian matrix and we evaluate the matrix at $a$, then it's still a matrix and therefore a linear map. This leads me to my third question:

Third question: what's the difference between the differential $df$ as I wrote it in my question and the Jacobian matrix of $f$?

Comment: You mean that $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$. If that is the case, then the differential coincides with the *gradient* $\nabla f\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$. If, as you wrote, $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, then the differential maps into the space of $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: I mean $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. So in this case, what are the domain and codomain of $df$? I guess by what you said $df : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$? Also, if this is the case then the question doesn't make sense since the domain and codomain of a contracting map have to be the same -- so I think something is wrong somewhere...?

Comment: At an abstract level, $df$ maps $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathrm{Lin}(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^n)$, the space of (bounded) linear maps of $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^n$. Which, concretely, equals $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, the space of $n\times n$ matrices. It must be that way, because $f$ has $n$ components and each one of them has $n$ derivatives, so the differential of $f$ must be an object with $n\times n$ entries.

Comment: I think maybe then I do indeed want to show that $df(a)$ is contracting, because then $df(a)$ is truly a linear map from $R^n$ to $R^n$. In this case, what should my abstract definition of $df(a)$ be? I guess I'd need to start with $|df(a)(x) - df(a)(y)|$ for arbitrary points $x,y \in R^n$ but I'm not sure how to explicitly write $df(a)(x) $.

Comment: It would have sense in any case to talk about contractions, since it suffices to have metric spaces as domain and codomain. In your case, you could consider the induced operator norm on the space of matrices, and prove/disprove that the differential is a contraction with respect to this metric. Or, of course you can prove that the linear map $df(a):\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a contraction, for every $a\in \R^n$, but this is not the same!

Comment: Hi MatteoDR, yes in that case I think I want to do the latter thing. My remaining confusion is how to write $df(a)(x)$ explicitly for an arbitrary point $x \in R^n$, because as I mentioned in a previous comment this is what I'd need for showing contractability.

Comment: In this case you can use the limit definition
\begin{equation}
df(a)x=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+hx)-f(a)}{h}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you did in your question, but the property you want to prove is false. Take for example the function $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin (t^2)}{2}\, dt.$$
This is a contraction mapping because
$$
\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \le \left\lvert \int_x^y \left\lvert\frac{\sin (t^2)}{2}\right\rvert\, dt\right\rvert \le \frac12 |x-y|.$$
However,
$$
f'(x)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2}$$
is not a contraction: its derivative is
$$
f''(x)=x\cos(x^2)$$
and it is clearly unbounded.

Comment: Great!  But you can of course prove that, for any fixed $z\in \mathbb{R}$,  $f'(z)$ is a contraction, when considered as a linear function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. the linear function $x\mapsto f'(z)x$. I think that this is what GreenCoffea was supposed to prove.

Comment: I kind of suspected that. In this $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ case, this amounts to proving that $|f'(x)|\le \rho<1$, which indeed is true with $\rho=1/2$.